# How to save a password in Google Chrome for Android?

Tags: google

I just don't understand how to save a **password** in android. Please  help me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Chrome, go to the Settings. Click on Passwords.
2. Enable "Save passwords".
3. Go to the site you intend to save the password. Enter your credentials.
4. Click Ok (Login, or whatever button the site uses). A prompt will appear asking if you want to save the password. Click Save. The password is now saved within Chrome.
5. Go to the Settings, click Passwords. Your credentials for sites will appear under the Passwords section. Clicking on a site will allow to modify the credentials.